# Thin server not timing out

Tags: ruby, http, timeout, webserver, thin

The code/documentation for Thin suggests that the default connection timeout is 30s. However, when I try to test this, it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

I'm using thin v1.5.0 (the latest).

```
# Test this using: curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/test. You will find that the request does not
# timeout after 30s.

require 'thin'

class SimpleAdapter
  def call(env)
    sleep 100
    body = ["hello!"]
    [
      200,
     { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' },
      body
    ]
  end
end

server = Thin::Server.new('127.0.0.1', 3000) do
  map '/test' do
    run SimpleAdapter.new
  end
end

server.start!
```

Comment: Could you reference the documentation that suggests the 30 second timeout?

Comment: If you look at the code, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT is set to 30s. Also, if you use the command-line runner and do 'thin -h', then help suggests the following: '-t, --timeout SEC Request or command timeout in sec (default: 30)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inline documentation states the following:

> Maximum number of seconds for incoming data to arrive before the connection is dropped.

And Thin correctly displays that behavior, that is, if you telnet into the server:

```
telnet localhost 3000
```

and wait for 30 seconds, it drops the connection. **However**, the cURL command already sends a complete HTTP request to the Thin server, which is why the timeout waiting for **incoming data** is never reached.